Lemma about a graph in Coq
I need to prove a Lemma in Coq, about a connected graph with certain properties:
the vertices of the graph are of type V:Type, and there is a function f: V -> nat which associates a natural number to each vertice in the graph. It is also known that, if two vertices v1 and v2 are adjacent, the following relation applies: f v1 = f v2 \/ f v1 = S (f v2) \/ S (f v1) = f v2. And we also know that there is an integer n for which, whenever f vi = n, for any vertice vj adjacent to vi, we have : f vj = f vi \/ f vj = S (f vi). There is at least one such vi in the graph.
I'd like to prove the following lemma: ~exist vn, path vi vn /\ f vn < f vi.
I tried this :
Section myGraph.

   Variable V   : Type.
   Variable vi  : V.
   Variable n   : nat.
   Variable adj : V -> V -> Prop.
   Variable f   : V -> nat.

   Hypothesis adj_relation   : forall v1 v2 : V, adj v1 v2 -> f v1 = f v2 \/ f v1 = S (f v2) \/ S (f v1) = f v2.
   Hypothesis nvalue         : f vi = n.
   Hypothesis both_ways      : forall v1 v2: V, adj v1 v2 -> adj v2 v1.
   Hypothesis special_vertex : forall vj v : V, f v = n -> adj v vj -> f vj = n \/ f vj = S n.

   (* The path relation *)
   Inductive path : V -> V -> Prop :=
     | path_refl  : forall v, path v v
     | path_step  : forall v1 v2, adj v1 v2 -> path v1 v2
     | path_trans : forall v1 v2 v3, path v1 v2 -> path v2 v3 -> path v1 v3.

   (* The graph is connected *)
   Hypothesis connected : forall v1 v2 : V, path v1 v2.

  (* Lemma to prove: There is no vertex vn such that f vn < f vi *)
  Lemma no_vertex_less_than_vi : ~ (exists vn : V, path vi vn /\ f vn < f vi).
  Proof.
    intros [vn H].
    assert (Hpath : path vn vi) by apply (connected vn vi).

    induction Hpath.
    - lia.
    - destruct (adj_relation v1 v2 H0) as [Hf_eq | [Hf_succ | Hf_pred]].
      + lia.
      + lia.
      + apply both_ways in H0.
        destruct (special_vertex v1 v2 nvalue) as [Hspec_eq | Hspec_succ].
        -- ?

    - ??

But I'm stuck on the last part.
How can I do that ?

(1) You say "if two vertices v1 and v2 are connected" but the code only has adj v1 v2 in adj_relation. (2) It's often easier to write a proof in English or you favorite natural language first, so you can use it as a reference to write the proof in Coq.

You're right. I've replaced 'connected' with 'adjacent' in the text. Sorry for the confusion.

Isn't the following graph a counterexample: 3 vertices v1, vi, vn, 2 undirected edges adj v1 vi, adj vi vn, and f v1 = f vi = 1, f vn = 0?

I think that the conterexample doesn't comply with the special_vertex hypothesis.

Oh, I see n is also a fixed constant now.

Your proof is badly started because you assume that you are looking at paths starting on vertices where the value n is reached, but the next vertices actually are only guaranteed to have a value larger than or equal to n.
But if you start from a vertex that has value larger than or equal to n, you are already able to prove the fact that you want for its neighbors.  So you should use this less strict hypothesis.
In the end, you don't need to have as hypothesis that n is reached once, you
only need to have as hypothesis that a value greater than n or equal to n is reached once.
I have a Coq script for this solution, but I refrain to distribute it because I don't know whether this would spoil the answer for a school assignment.

Using the hints given by Yves, i.e changing the nvalue hypothesis and the path definition, I've been able to find a proof:
Lemma helper: forall (n1 n2:nat),
   n1 >= n2 <-> n1 = n2 \/ n1 > n2.  
Proof.
   intros n1 n2.
   lia.
Qed.

Section myGraph.

   Variable V   : Type.
   Variable vi  : V.
   Variable n   : nat.
   Variable adj : V -> V -> Prop.
   Variable f   : V -> nat.

   Hypothesis adj_relation   : forall v1 v2 : V, adj v1 v2 -> f v1 = f v2 \/ f v1 = S (f v2) \/ S (f v1) = f v2.
   Hypothesis nvalue         : f vi >= n.
   Hypothesis both_ways      : forall v1 v2: V, adj v1 v2 -> adj v2 v1.
   Hypothesis special_vertex : forall vj v: V, f v = n -> adj v vj -> f vj = n \/ f vj = S n.

   Inductive path : V -> V -> Prop :=
     | path_refl : forall v, path v v
     | path_step : forall v1 v2 v3, path v1 v2 -> adj v2 v3 -> path v1 v3.

   (* The graph is connected *)
   Hypothesis connected : forall v1 v2 : V, path v1 v2.

   Lemma no_vertex_less_than_n: forall (v: V), f v >= n.
   Proof.
       intros v.
       assert (H: path v vi). apply connected.
       induction H.
       - easy.
       - apply helper in nvalue.
         destruct nvalue as [Heq | Hgt].
         + apply IHpath. apply both_ways in H0.
           pose (special_vertex v2 v3 Heq H0) as HRef.
           lia.
         + apply IHpath. pose (adj_relation v2 v3 H0) as HRef.
           lia.
   Qed.

End myGraph.


It turns out you can also prove the statement without changing the definition of path.

The next two subgoals are provable by lia.
I would switch to a different presentation of paths, one that adds adjacent nodes one at a time:
Inductive path' (v0 : V) : V -> Prop :=
  path'0 : path' v0 v0
| path'S : forall u w, path' v0 u -> adj u w.

And then prove that path' and path are equivalent.  For the part of the proof that you already did, that should not change anything.
Proving by induction over path' should give you simpler work, but you may have to load the induction, that is, prove a statement that looks stronger.
